# how can I transfer the data to another component (useEffect problem)

Tags: reactjs

In useEffect, I retrieve the data from the server and store it in the "products" array:

```
const { url } = props;
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      setLoadingSpinner(true);
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      setLoadingSpinner(false);
      const loadedProducts = [];

      for (const key in responseData) {
        loadedProducts.push({
          id: key,
          name: responseData[key].name,
          description: responseData[key].description,
          price: responseData[key].price,
          image: responseData[key].image,
          processor: responseData[key].processor,
        });
      }
      setProducts(loadedProducts);
      setIsDataLoaded(true);
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, [url, isDataLoaded]);
```

I pass it to the ProductDetail component:

```
<ProductDetail products={products}></ProductDetail>
```

I always get a null value in the ProductDetail component:

```
function ProductDetail(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.products && params.productId) {
        const product = props.products.find(product => product.id === params.productId);
        setProduct(product);
      }
    }, [props.products, params.productId]);

    console.log(product)
```

I realized that when useEffect is run for the first time, my "products" array is still empty and it sends it to the component, so it's not good. But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I don't see why you would get `null` because the `products` variable is initially `[]`

Comment: Because in the ProductDetail component, my "product" array is null and I would fill it with the product selected from the "products" array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong here. I'm going to start with something that seems tangential at first but it will lead to a better answer.

In `ProductDetail` you introduce a new state called `product`. You then, in a `useEffect`, find the product from the list & product id in props and set this back into the state item. This would be unnecessary state duplication (even if not copying a prop verbatim into state, a value derived directly from props still counts) and is going to increase the surface areas for bugs in your application (this is probably the most common beginner's error).

You actually don't need that state item, you just need `useMemo`:

```
function ProductDetail(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    
    const product = useMemo(() => {
      if (props.products && params.productId) {
        return props.products.find(product => product.id === params.productId);
      }
    }, [props.products, params.productId]);

    console.log(product)
```

To solve the issue with the product not being found briefly whilst then products load you can either (a) conditionally render the component so this code doesn't even run in the first place when `products` isn't fetched yet. Or (b) Change the `ProductDetail` so that it effectively does nothing until the product is found.

**Solution A**

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(null); // We change the default to null to be able to distinguish empty list case from loading case.

// ...

{products !== null && <ProductDetail products={products}></ProductDetail>}
```

**Solution B**

```
function ProductDetail(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    
    const product = useMemo(() => {
      if (props.products && params.productId) {
        return props.products.find(product => product.id === params.productId);
      }
    }, [props.products, params.productId]);

    if (!product) return null // Return early (do nothing) whilst product is not found

    // ... your original render contents
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried what you said, but it says undefined for "product" in the "ProductDetail" component. The data from the server must be good because it is displayed in "AvailableProducts".

Comment: It will do, at least on the first few renders. This would be expected, hence why you to need to ensure your component is null-safe and doesn't blow up when it is not defined. The early return in option b, should be enough.

Comment: So there will indeed be neither null nor undefined. But nothing happens. 
It gets stuck at this line and that's it:

if (!product) return null

It doesn't even take these into account: 
  console.log(product)
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>{params.productId}</h1>
        <p>{product}</p>
      </div>
    );

I don't understand what the problem is :(

Comment: Above the ` if (!product) return null ` can you log both `params.productId` and `props.products` and report back the results? It will probably print many times, but i only need to know the final values before it gets stuck.

Comment: The params.productId is printed correctly. The id of the product that I click on.
However, props.product is undefined.
It is in the console:
P5TdeQvMzD ProductDetail.js:14
undefined ProductDetail.js:15
P5TdeQvMzD ProductDetail.js:14
undefined ProductDetail.js:15

Comment: console.log(params.productId)
  console.log(props.product)

Comment: There is no `product` prop here only `products`. You are logging the wrong thing (and probably using the wrong thing int he component. You want to log the variable `product` that is returned from `useMemo`

Comment: I noticed it when I sent it, but it's undefined either way. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll keep trying and see if I can get it to work.